# Which are the causes of the EDoubleFree error rare exception?

Tags: delphi, exception, memory, delphi-10-seattle

As i was testing my application i was in this scenario

Delphi applications built with Delphi 10:

version at build 1 was running together with version at build 2.

So quite similar applications except for a bug fixed in the build 2.

i closed  the 2 applications together and EurekaLog showed me the error clearly (raised by Build 1):

> Application made attempt to free the same memory block twice:
>   $220B4A80 OBJECT [TList] 20 bytes.

Since i was not recording my monitor i do not know exactly what i did, but i was not able to reproduce how to get the error.

The error was generated by a call to

```
MyList.Free;
```

where `MyList` is a `TList`

I tired to reproduce it again but without success.

The bug fix was not related with this `TList`, it seems that the simultaneous executino of 2 similar applications generated the error and there has been some coincidence.

It seems a Delphi bug, in principle an application should not try to free the same memory twice.

Anyone had experience with this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that some code, most likely your code, called Free twice on the same object

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my code frees that `TList` only once on `FormDestroy`, i double checked. You do not think that 2 separate exes can create this problem?

Comment: Not unless you have some code that passes data between the two applications (and even then it would be hard to do). Set a breakpoint at TList.Destroy in System.Classes.PAS and see which TLists are freed. There will probably be a lot of RTL/VCL TLists, but you should be able to determine if "Self" in there refer to your list or not. Once you find these, you should be able to determine from where they are called.

Comment: I did that, my list is destroyed once as expected by reading the code. My gut feelign goes for the never-reproduced-before Delphi bug.I am not able to reproduce it anymore by the way.

Comment: Almost certainly a defect in your code. It's just your wishful thinking that it might be a defect in the Delphi libraries.

Comment: Anyway, I can see three questions in your post. What exactly is your specific question?

Comment: somehow is "can you give me an hand in reproducing this exception?". i had it only once. The fact i suspect of a Delphi bug is just because i use IDEs everyday and i often face bugs in "boundary places", so it is likely the effect of my experience. Anwyay somehow you all tell me that there is something in my code. The fact is that i cannot reproduce the issue with my code. I just remember that when i was testing i had 2 instances of 2 almost equal applications running. Basically i long for an expert advice.This code is pretty old, i guess 10 years at least and this exception was never seen.

Comment: That's a fourth question now. And not one that you asked in the main body above. It's unlikely to be related to their being two processes running. Most likely is simply that EurekaLog is correct.

Comment: ok i accept the downvote and i found your comments very useful, i edited the question leaving the only question that matters `Anyone had experience with this exception?`

Comment: I certainly have experienced this issue. When I have destroyed an object that has already been destroyed.

Comment: There's only one possible answer to this question and that is "yes".

Comment: I mean, for a "no" answer, everyone except you have to reach a consensus. This is not a suitable format for this site.

Comment: Of course there's the definitive answer that "I have not seen it but perhaps some other has", but I doubt that that will be helpful to you.